# What configuration supports iOS bundle id auto-generation?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

I downloaded the app's source code from here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui

I opened it with Xcode 13.4.1 and select the `Fruta iOS` target, I found the bundle id is **com.example.apple-samplecode.fruta**

[image]

After switching the `Team` config to my `Person Team` (signed in with `Apple ID`), the `bundle id` is automatically switched to **com.example.apple-samplecode.fruta*BxxxxxxxxA*** (suddenly a suffix `BxxxxxxxxA` is added)

I would like to know what it is and how to achieve that for other projects.

I want to share the source code with my friends so they are able to sign with their own Personal Team and test the project on an actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build setting for `PROJECT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` in this project looks like this:

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "com.example.apple-samplecode.fruta${SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR}";
```

That variable is in turn defined in `SampleCode.xcconfig`:

```
// The `SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR` configuration is to make it easier to build
// and run a sample code project. Once you set your project's development team,
// you'll have a unique bundle identifier. This is because the bundle identifier
// is derived based on the 'SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR' value. Do not use this
// approach in your own projects—it's only useful for sample code projects because
// they are frequently downloaded and don't have a development team set.
SAMPLE_CODE_DISAMBIGUATOR=${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM}
```

You can get a similar behavior simply by editing a project and setting the PROJECT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER setting to something like `com.example.my-example-app${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM}`